# Custom delete handling for an entity using SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'd like to implement some custom delete handling. We've got some types of entity which only get marked as deleted in the database. The real removing from the database is done by a scheduled process.

Now it's easy to replace the delete method in the Admin class, but I've got some issues with the batch action. It wouldn't make so much sense to create a child bundle to either modify the general or to create a new method in the CRUDController class iny my eyes.

So I'd tend to create a custom ModelManager (based on the one of DoctrineORMAdminBundle) and put the business logic into this. I couldn't find any documentation about this part.

Would this be a clean solution? It's somehow a pity that the logic is spread into so much places. :/

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 7):

You can use [SoftDeleteable doctrine behavior](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md)

Install the [Gedmo Doctrine2 extensions bundle](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md)

Once you have install and configure the bundle, update your entity to add soft delete behavior:

```
namespace Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 */
class Article
{

    # ...

    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }
}
```

I have already used it with Sonata and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the bundle. I'm already using the extensions in another project, but somehow missed the SoftDeleteable.

On the other hand I'd really like to know how to solve the issue just with the SonataAdminBundle. I'm still evaluating if it's fitting our quite specific CRUD needs or if we start from scratch.

Comment: @Picoss Sonata admin how to undelete which has already been deleted.Basically i want to acheive archive/unarchive feature any ideas.I have deleted the element using softedelete now i wish to undelete is there any inbuild stuff which i am missing

Comment: @wilsonrufus Check my bundle SonataExtraAdminBundle on how to use the trash manager : https://github.com/picoss/SonataExtraAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/trash_manager.md